# DataTemplate Error in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

i have error in my code in this place:

```
   <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Opis}" Margin="15" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap"  MaxHeight="370"  />
       <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="400" Height="180" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill"/>
     </StackPanel> </DataTemplate>
```

I have a warning "Invalid XAML". What is wrong with my code? I can debug my app and it worked ok...

Comment: Is this your whole XAML file? Where does this code come from - Resources/ItemTemplate? Are you sure that this fragment causes the error?

Comment: No, this code is a part of layout, it work good, but I don't know why VS2013 underline the fragment from <DataTemplate> to </DataTemplate>. It is cover by <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>.

Comment: Your Image is not in a grid by the way. Not sure it is your problem but you should remove your Grid.Column stuff.

Comment: What is the error displayed when you hover the underlined text fragments? You may also rebuild your application or even restart VS2013. I noticed that the XAML errors are sometimes no longer valid and this is only recognized after rebuild and in the worst case restart.

Comment: I removed Grid.Column stuff and all works like before. It look like in this photo: http://oi59.tinypic.com/6p6bzb.jpg

I have only "Invalid XAML"